# Android sdk platform-tools install error on windows xp

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, platform

I have windows XP and Eclipse Java EE Indigo SR1 installed on my laptop. I installed android SDK r16 and ADT 16.0.1. My first problem is that instead of having "Android SDK and AVD Manager" in my window menu in eclipse, I have "Android SDK Manager" and "AVD Manager" separately. Is something wrong with my Eclipse or what?

[image: image 1]

My second problem is that I cannot install SDK Platform-tools, when I click on "Android SDK Manager" this window appears:

[image: image 2]

Not only this window does not contain any entry named "sdk platform-tools", cf. [this picture from android documentation](http://developer.android.com/images/sdk_manager_packages.png),but also when i try to install "Archive for Windows x86" I get this page:

[image: image 3]

as you see the "Installed" button is disabled. What can I do to install sdk platform-tools on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first problem is that instead of having "Android SDK and AVD Manager" in my window menu in eclipse, I have "Android SDK Manager" and "AVD Manager" separately. Is something wring with my eclipse or what?

This is a new behavior starting from ADT 16. Do not worry!

> My second problem is that I cannot install SDK Platform-tools, when I click on "Android SDK Manager" this window appears:

Other problems can be connected with the version of your JDK. To use Android SDK you should use only JDK 5 or JDK 6. Check maybe you have installed JDK7 (it is not supported still)

Comment: Try to install newer version of JDK. Here is the link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html You need to download JDK 6 Update 30.

Comment: Moreover, you have installed a lot of different versions of Java. Try to uninstall them all and install just JDK.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll do that and let you know of the result.

Comment: I uninstalled all of different versions of Java I had, then installed JDK 6 Update 30. But still the same problem exists! I even uninstalled eclipse and Android SDK and reinstalled them again, but nothing new happened!

Comment: Do you have a permanent connection to the Internet? Maybe you're working behind a proxy? Then you should configure your proxy settings.

Comment: I have a permanent internet connection, but since I am in Iran and Google prevents Iranians from accessing to the repository website (i.e. dl-ssl.google.com) I have to use a proxy server (I have already configured the required proxy settings in eclipse in order to use the proxy server), but this proxy server has not made any problem in any of the steps I have done till now, neither for eclipse nor for other software; so I think this proxy server may not be the cause. I have even disabled my antivirus, but nothing changes in Android SDK Manager window!

Comment: Here is the problem. Find SDKManager.exe file in your Android SDK folder. There should be a tab (or smthg like that) for configuring proxy. Configure it there and update your SDK from there. Your eclipse proxy settings do not allow you to update SDK. Good luck!

Comment: WOW!! that was brilliant dude! it is working now!! thank you very very much!!

Comment: @Yury So What are the Configuration settings can u please update about this?

Comment: @Yury I am facing same problems in Windows 7 , can u please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: There is a tab in SDKManager to configure proxy. Insert your settings for proxy there and update your Android SDK from there.

Comment: @Yury What will be the proxy settings there?

Comment: It depends on the settings of your proxy server. I do not know. You should ask your administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I hads the same problem. Just checked, and the behaviour on my side was due to an incorrect proxy setting - the proxy configured sent back some data, which the SDK Manager has probably tried to interprete, but having failed that, it did not display any error message, just silently ignored the error.

So recommendation: check if your network/proxy settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue. please try...
click on packages menu then reload
i'll hope this will help you